# How can I read only some special rows from my sql database?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, eclipse

How could I retrieve the rows that match a particular value (for instance the one that has the name `peter`)

Here is my helper class:

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    String Order = "_id DESC";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null,Order,null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

And here is my `Cursor` to `Listview` adapter class:

```
Cursor cursor = DBAFT.getAllRows();
```

Comment: Next time, please don't change the nature of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String where = "name like '%peter%'"
```

Comment: if you have rows matching peter it will work. so check the column name ... i have used name ... it may be possible you have any other column name then use that. you can try out any combination of text instead of peter which you think would result some set of rows. Also give it a try the solution mentioned by Loc Ha above.

Answer (score 3):

You can use rawQuery.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name like ?";

Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] { "%" + "petter" + "%"});
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Any error message?